# Omniauth + Rails not updating database and signing in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, omniauth

When attempting to sign into my website, the user is redirected back to the homepage without having been signed in. (The button to sign-in is still present)

My database is creating new entries for these users, but isn't updating any of the information. (All columns except id, provider, and uid are empty)

I'm not even sure where to start looking to solve this error. This was working before I added another column to my User model.

Please help!

SessionsController

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
layout false
def new
end

def create
    begin
        @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env['omniauth.auth'])
        session[:user_id] = @user.id
        flash[:success] = "Welcome, #{@user.name}!"
    rescue
        flash[:warning] = "There was an error while trying to authenticate you..."
    end
redirect_to root_path
end

def destroy
    if current_user
        session.delete(:user_id)
        flash[:success] = 'See you!'
    end
        redirect_to root_path
end
end
```

UsersController

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: session[:user_id])
end

helper_method :current_user

def show

end

def edit
    @all_events = Event.all
    @user_events = current_user.userevents.build
end

def update
    params[:events][:id].each do |event|
        if !event.empty?
            current_user.userevents.build(:event_id => event)
        end
    end
    eventlist = Event.all
    usereventlist = Userevent.all
    eventstring = ""
    Userevent.dedupe
    usereventlist.each do |ue|
        if current_user.id == ue.user_id
            eventlist.each do |ei|
                if ei.id == ue.event_id
                    eventstring += ei.event + " "
                end
            end
        end
    end
    current_user.events = eventstring
    current_user.save!
    redirect_to current_user
end  
end
```

User Model (user.role is the line that was added)

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
class << self
    def from_omniauth(auth_hash)
        user = find_or_create_by(uid: auth_hash['uid'], provider: auth_hash['provider'])
        user.name = auth_hash['info']['name']
        user.location = auth_hash['info']['location']
        user.image_url = auth_hash['info']['image']
        user.url = auth_hash['info']['urls']['user.provide.capitalize']
        user.email = auth_hash['info']['email']
        user.events = nil
        user.school = nil
        user.role = nil
        user.save!
        user
    end
end
has_many :userevents
end
```

migration#_create_users.rb

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
def change
create_table :users do |t|
    t.string :provider, null: false
    t.string :uid, null: false
    t.string :name
    t.string :location
    t.string :image_url
    t.string :url
    t.timestamps null: false
end
    add_index :users, :provider
    add_index :users, :uid
    add_index :users, [:provider, :uid], unique: true
end
end
```

migration#_add_roles_to_users.rb

```
class AddRolesToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
def change
  add_column :users, :role, :string
end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
def from_omniauth(auth_hash)
  user = find_or_initialize_by(uid: auth_hash['uid'], provider: auth_hash['provider']).tap do |user|
    user.name = auth_hash['info']['name']
    user.location = auth_hash['info']['location'          user.image_url = auth_hash['info']['image']
    user.url = auth_hash['info']['urls']['user.provide.capitalize']
    user.email = auth_hash['info']['email']
    user.events = nil
    user.school = nil
    user.role = nil
  end
  user.save
end
```